# Render an ASCII maze

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

look! It's an ASCII maze! Soo coolzors, amazeballs and stuff.

```
+-+-----+---+
| |     |   |
| |  ++   | |
| |  ++ +-+ |
|       |   |
+-------+ | |
|         | |
+---------+-+
```

But, but, but... it's a pain to work out which direction all the parts of the maze are going. I just want to draw the layout and the maze make itself sooper kul without loads of time.

What if I could just draw this in...

```
#############
# #     #   #
# #  ##   # #
# #  ## ### #
#       #   #
######### # #
#         # #
#############
```

That would be soo sweet!

---

The rules (Because rules is cools):

- Write code to convert a string into an ascii maze and output the result.
- Any non-whitespace character will be read as a wall.
- Each char of wall will decide which character to be based on it's neighbours (only in North, South, East and West directions).

  - If a char has no non-whitespace neighbours, it will be a plus sign (+).
  - If a char has neighbours in both vertical (North-South) and horizontal (East-West) directions, it will be a plus sign (+).
  - If a char has neighbours only in a vertical (North-South) direction, it will be a pipe symbol (|).
  - If a char has neighbours only in a horizontal (East-West) direction, it will be a minus sign (-).
- The Input can be a single string (with lines separated by newline characters, or an array of strings).
- All input characters will be printable ASCII characters, you don't need to deal with extended charsets.
- Use any old language you please.
- If there is white space before a line, it should be the same amount on each line. Any white space after each line of output is fine.
- Attempt to solve it with the smallest number of bytes.

---

## Test cases:

### 1: Frame

Input:

```
##########
#        #
#        #
#        #
##########
```

Output:

```
+--------+
|        |
|        |
|        |
+--------+
```

### 2: Classic maze

Input:

```
#################
        #       #
# ##### # ##### #
#   # # #     # #
# # # # ##### # #
#   # #       # # 
### # ####### # #
#   # #    #  # # 
# ### # ## # ##
#     # ##    #  
#################
```

Output:

```
--------+-------+
        |       |
| --+-+ | ----+ |
|   | | |     | |
| + | | +---- | |
|   | |       | | 
+-- | +----+- | |
|   | |    |  | | 
| --+ | ++ | -+
|     | ++    |  
+-----+-++----+--
```

### 3: Green eggs, man.

Input:

```
I do not like green eggs and ham.
I do not like them, sam I am.
Would you like them here or there?
I would not like them anywhere!
```

Output:

```
| ++ +++ ++++ +++++ +++- -++ ----
| ++ +++ ++++ +++++ +++ + +++
+-+++ +++ ++++ ++++ ++++ ++ +++---
| +++-+ +++ ++++ ++-+ +++++++++
```

### 4: Icicles

Input:

```
Word Icicle!
Word Icicle 
Word  cicle 
 ord  cicle 
 ord   icle 
 ord   i le 
 or    i le 
 or    i l  
 or      l  
 or         
  r
```

Output:

```
++++ ++++++-
++++ ++++++ 
++++  +++++ 
 +++  +++++ 
 +++   ++++ 
 +++   | ++ 
 ++    | ++ 
 ++    | |  
 ++      |  
 ++         
  |
```

Comment: Cab we take input as a string array for each line?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that all characters (except newlines of course) are printable ASCII?

Comment: @LiefdeWen Sure, why not?

Comment: @user202729 That sounds like a sensible restriction.

Comment: Shouldn't the third line of green eggs and ham end with `---`?

Comment: @LiefdeWen I should really have spotted that. Completely correct.

Comment: Results for mixed neighbours still unclear; not sure why icicles would have any `-`s at all or why classic maze doesn't have four `+`s on the bottom row.

Comment: @Neil I've corrected those. The answer to the icicles one was that I was scrolled past the first line when I first converted it, then fixed up the top line when I saw it... (doh.jpg)

Comment: are we allowed to take the input as a square padded with spaces (i.e. matrix)? Is the output allowed to have extra whitespace around it? Also, do you really mean `smallest number of characters`, not bytes?

Comment: I think that 1) the classic maze should have a `+` in the middle of the 1st row 2) the `!` of Icicles should be replaced with a `-`. Could you please double-check these ones?

Comment: Attention @all! I can't proof read for toffee, today. Corrected yet more of my errors.

Comment: By `whitespace`, do you just mean just space? I don't want to have to support tabs and you probably don't want me to transform newlines either

Comment: @JoKing All input characters are printable ASCII. Tabs are not printable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>57</s> 35 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

–22 thanks to [a novel solution by ngn](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44051129#44051129).

Anonymous tacit function taking a character matrix as argument.

```apl
{⊃'+-|+'↓⍨2⊥5 4 2⊃¨⊂⍱∘⌽⍨' '≠,⍵}⌺3 3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLNSsNAEMfvfYq/5LBKWzHGQm@e8wSeQ7NNivmQtKUE9WIhtDEBxYtHEYTiTaggghcfZV6kbj42McYN7OxkfvOfyWSNC6dvhobjW7vdmKK7S4qXrNu/6jKKHijdHFP8MsAJhF1@byi@ofSNVo@UfIkgA6P1U4/S92tKPjVoQgNDqBqlW6Y0FhRkK9sLR8mPtZMzBSSxX7lVJIuxDmOdMQZQj/4Uqph/TmWWqkIdtvtTGhWkVVA3UFr5vibkUxGSaahIos0oqBXkRMrpQM6oNROpVX4VRfdMh@nD82dwJuccVsC5B25ZUxieCdtwD8XvajIzm7s9TA0XOor4mT93TIT@vAZg84DDDzIn4Ke5yCLHGjqiSrjIiL26JVq95rdovU/pbXZrxJ5uKfmg@PlA1ApM6KPJyBE5Pw)

`{`…`}⌺3 3` on each 3-by-3 neighbourhood, apply the following function:

`,⍵` ravel (flatten)

`' '≠` Boolean where non-space

`⍱∘⌽⍨` that NOR it's reverse (incl. neither top NOR bottom, neither left NOR right)

`5 4 2⊃¨⊂` pick 5<sup>th</sup>, 4<sup>th</sup>, and 2<sup>nd</sup> element from that entire list
  i.e. empty self, no vertical, no horizontal

`2⊥` evaluate in base-2 (binary)
  i.e. ≥4:empty self; 3:no neighbours; 2:no horizontal neighbours; 1:no vertical; 0: has both

`'+-|+'↓⍨` drop that many elements from this string
  i.e. empty self:; alone:`+`; vertical neighbour(s) only:`|+`; horizontal:`-|+`; both:`+-|+`

`⊃` pick the first element (pad with space if non are available)
  i.e. empty self: ; alone:`+`; vertical neighbour(s) only:`|`; horizontal:`-`; both:`+`

---

## Old solution

Anonymous tacit function taking a character matrix as argument.

```apl
{' +-|+'⊃⍨1⍳⍨(' '=5⊃,⍵),(∧/,⊢)∨/2 2⍴1⌽' '≠(9⍴0 1)/,⍵}⌺3 3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLBTsJAEIbvPMVvetgSirA0JHgwnnkCzw1dCrFQUyCEqCcTUpBNNF48Gi8Sr2JiTHyZeRHcLV1qxW2ys7PzzT/Tab3LsOrPvDAKttsuze@vGCrV6wqj5S3JNSf5rozNwE6b6soh@VF2bEpeaw4tX8qUrGsNNEhuOK2@FUWLZ/tEuXXwck3TN7T6cuEqcbTAXRViVmHBgl563zlWesydlNlBBvuVu4/oGCsxVuqiCV7/U2jP/HPKsjgHbx32ZxUqGGshbyCz5j4nzLMnDFNQMcQhYyFXMBPJpgMzo4OZGK3srWj@wNrwIwyjMcL@hUAQCzGECIIRvKGPnjc4Vh@uyIx7YuBg5A3Qxi5@Hk1CH7NokgPoiVggirUTi7NUZJpiBR1VZTbVxFHeEiVvNH8kubBJ3lHypHe5odWn/qlUrdhHu9PvhCrnBw)

`{`…`}⌺3 3` on each 3-by-3 neighbourhood, apply the following function:

`,⍵` ravel (flatten)

`(`…`)/` filter using the following mask:

`9⍴0 1` cyclically reshape `[0,1]` to length 9 (selects N, W, E, S)

`' '≠` Boolean where non-space

`1⌽` rotate one step left; `[W,E,S,N]`

`2 2⍴` reshape to 2-by-2 matrix; `[[W,E],[S,N]]`

`∨/` row-wise OR reduction: `[horizontal,vertical]`

`(`…`)` apply the following tacit function:

`⊢` the identity; `[horizontal,vertical]`

`∧/,` preceded by its AND reduction; `[both,horizontal,vertical]`

`(`…`),` prepend the following:

`,⍵` ravel (flatten) the neighbourhood

`5⊃` pick the 5<sup>th</sup> element (itself)

`' '=` Boolean if space (i.e. empty)

Now we have `[empty,both,horizontal,vertical]`

`1⍳⍨` index of leftmost 1 (gives 5 if no neighbours at all)

`' +-|+'⊃⍨` use that to pick symbol

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>181</s> 168 bytes

thanks to Leaky Nun for -13 bytes

```python
m=input()
f=lambda x,y:(['']+m+[''])[y+1][x:x+1]>' '
print[[(c<'!')*' 'or'+-|+'[f(x+1,y)|f(x-1,y)|2*f(x,y+1)|2*f(x,y-1)]for x,c in enumerate(r)]for y,r in enumerate(m)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vZHNjoIwFIX3fYqjLAqCJppZmWFm7RO4ICwYqMIMbU2FCInvzpTKbzSZ3XTR3nPv19Pe9lIXqRS7JpYJ85fLZcP9TFzKwnbIyc8j/pVEqLx6bweUhi5328UJancbBtW@0ssHBSUXlYkiCOz4nS6os9Ipqai7vrs0ONma8mrnroO1CXYrHXraYgjXWyc8SaUPipEJMFFypqKC2eqRrz01z3MnbDh84H/PJG1ByVtb4HsCmL5B6eZbZsLWFefxFES/JCGsYjHah129NQG1hkE9UAvd@FuN@0IytZm4DRvmNqaOYe29TarjexITbk72zha62/TgS9SaoOhhM42dmdSDnTc47fOARELIAnn2w3BWjOnPOJ@viESCNOKbduscKlLGPVwjjgM64CjLPEEty5FAyhSD/siiDT4fNjfDzZz0QfWtRRbmPkepEhziLM51wjgPGoPGqPFS40lj1HitMdV40ug0Jjr8BQ)

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 110 bytes

I/O format: array of strings.

```javascript
a=>a.map((s,y)=>s.replace(/\S/g,(_,x)=>'+|-+'[[-1,p=0,1,2].map(c=>p|=(a[y+c%2]||0)[x+~-c%2]>' '?c&1||2:0)|p]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ldBBa4MwFAfwu5/ijbAlwWjV4yDuvPMOO1gZIbXF4kzQMVoI@@puxrpGq4zlEPHHy@P/3lF8ilY2pf4IarUruj3vBE9F@C40IS07U562YVPoSsiCbLYvmwMjb@z0w9g3gY@zLIiZ5hGLWZLbV5Kn2nAisrMv75PcmIhmJ/8r6H9SDPhJPsTGJI8RNTqntJOqblVVhJU6kD3JPACM3IOZJUDQn/52CVmYE0IOwc3D8cBNldtrEsLLaXhUZU3wtsYUfLBfz/sr/XUCcILAZIoxCprFtjgLdcGF@Oja2RlhrF2pRtPel/rhAnc1g9gHC@v574peVbODZ1nKqrgb2jkCjoArsCKwIOAKrAlMBRYEfgUcmc5Ku28)

Or [**108 bytes**](https://tio.run/##bZDLCsIwEEX3/YqBoEloGtouC4kfErMIsYqiTTAiLQR/vbb1gY/exTD3MHMZ5mCuJtjz3l@yxm3qfit6I6ThJ@MJCayjQoaHsawdjJUY8AqnMUuxUlnBvMhZwUo9DVkhfRTEqC61i1LHmFPVprdsNNOiXRYxllVOo9eVpbS3rgnuWPOj25EtUQmA4pxj9Cms2ZsDglFj/eNoorMcoV8O8zkvwfz8X/73nYmm0x8CCAmBH9y@IRhT@uzWzdD3dw) by using a matrix of characters instead.

Answer (score 5):

## MATLAB, <strike>113</strike> <strike>110</strike> 101 bytes

```
function F(A)
B=A>32
c=[1 1 1]
f=@(c)conv2(B,c,'s')>1
h=f(c)
v=f(c')
char((13*h+92*v-94*(h&v)).*B+32)
```

Converts input to logical, applies convolution in horizontal and vertical and combines the outputs to make the corresponding chars.

3 bytes saved by @Adriaan for telling me that you can clog the output in PPCG :P

9 bytes saved thanks to numerous @flawr comments!

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>49</s> 47 bytes

Thanks to *[FrownyFrog](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/74681)* for -2 bytes!

```
' +|-+'{~~:&' '*1+h&.|:+2*h=:g&.|.*g=:' '=#{.}.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5dT4MwGIXv@yuOkgwH2MxdNqJemZB474XxgoyOokBNYVmWffx1LJWPss0mlPfpeTjlq7mlODK4a4R6DxZgWDQu/MO97@5PJzZz4XoPvpjRA/OXnghZqkfqpSHTSejs6ZE2c8JXQiKgeMQL1vq5@2B4wtsrqp88q6taZWWKz7lO2tPl5Liqk6zUtzrDIg669e84utbcHw2e9alJMLxNmeHONA4sw3L6NgfEKrmUnF5Cr5mNDHf01pV/JhESiVLWyLNvjlRxXoKnaYW4TCDigp4ZteBFgCouEKFN3@UmT7CTmzGG4IpDqhYUf9YFWyNNOnT/btvmN0R3qATRKlvlmizAH6ADXAKmgA5wBTAApoAWMMIv)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 92 bytes

```
\S
0
(?<=(.)*)0(?=(?>.*\n(?<-1>.)*)0)|0(?=(.)*)(?<=0(?>(?<-2>.)*\n.*))
1
T`d`+|`\b.\b
T`d`-+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY6xboMwEIZ3P8UfsQBprKRzAzNzK3XxAIktQAUjOURRpLw75RxiQ5PeAPfdff5to/paF8MgPtmWhenHPuRRHG3DdB@mCY@FHmebXWKH0c3OqSdzhIS277QVmsdRxHbsK5f5@paLAxcHC5v1MASuWICp/m29O@sfI@fNjtoN3N@GWZ5M62BmzBx4x2c8O4HLmaz7B8zd8dBevJllkB1016OpfxRKo5SGKssTCi1RFS3HH6WvVPuGU9EiA62p2Hd3biSu3dk7qJRR6AyBUemYcrHSImi85Xqh/YpSxhgjkR3rY6NWc8AdMAGeAUvABHgBcIAl0BMAD78) Requires rectangular input. Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\S
0
```

Change all non-spaces to `0`s.

```
(?<=(.)*)0(?=(?>.*\n(?<-1>.)*)0)|0(?=(.)*)(?<=0(?>(?<-2>.)*\n.*))
1
```

Look for all `0`s with another `0` immediately above or below in the same column and change them to a 1. The `1`s are now the places with vertical neighbours, while the `0`s have no vertical neighbours.

```
T`d`+|`\b.\b
```

Look for all digits with no horizontal neighbours. The `0`s have no vertical neighbours either, so they become `+`s, while the `1`s have vertical neighbours, so they become `|`s.

```
T`d`-+
```

The remaining digits have horizontal neighbours. The `1`s also have vertical neighbours, so they become `+`s, while the `0`s only have horizontal neighbours, so they become `-`s.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 336 bytes

```python
def g(s):
 h,j,s=' +|-+','',s.splitlines()
 s+=['']
 for n in range(len(s)):
  s[n]+=' '
  for i in range(len(s[n])-1):
   l,r,k=s[n][i-1],s[n][i+1],0
   try:u=s[n-1][i]
   except:u=' '
   try:d=s[n+1][i]
   except:d=' '
   if not s[n][i]==' ':
    k+=1
    if not u==d==' ':k+=1
    if not l==r==' ':k+=2
   j+=h[k]
  j+='\n'
 print(j)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/RaoQwFETf71dcyEOUxFLbt4V8ifWh1KhRiZJkoQv@u02iscWlVzDDzMlcXR6un/X7tjWyxS6z@Q2w5wO3giJbC0Y5pdy@2GVSblJa2iwHtExUlNaA7WxQo9JoPnUns0lq3xAq0Fa6Zr6Deh0odaF8nBdlRHHiho8iWJUqyprvinn1GmJnHrd7iH1WqTpY8vtLLs67@4KINAFhV6RJiGpRzw737loEOy7HkYkyioO4C9Hs8TWZhDBn8haSgYm@GsM@r@iH9psWo7TLhnzrMkoIoTmAV5Sy4hgGKx6z/iN/WX8xFZDrQLpA0gkEY4LnCSTm5GB253gSeTKpjSD8KXmGSIIwYfEF545EwdM37/@z/QA)

I had to use a lot of code to deal with edge case errors.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 143 bytes

```c
char**y,*z,h,v;f(char**x){for(y=x;*y;++y)for(z=*y;*z;++z)if(*z-32){h=z[1]-32|z[-1]-32;v=y[1][z-*y]-32|y[-1][z-*y]-32;*z=h?v?43:45:(v?'|':43);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVLbjoIwEH3nKyaSjW2BrLu6LzbEL@ALWB8MkaUJoEFDbJFvZ6e0aHWziUNC55w5c@kli36ybBiyYtcwJkOmwiJseU4McaFdfmiIjC@cSR4EkmqoYgRMIVZU5ISpaPlJuyJW6ccW3atKo9HhbSyRSlXE5BiQOnCDWCIuNu1mtVyvvtak3cyv8/VqSXnfD6I@Q7UTNaGdB2gaCz66ejJgVbqFWMPOm8Ffm4VI@89m6Mn822rURu@sltYK36od2n5TzqMantT3uv@o/cfaVm9@cFfDxID/4i7dM4FFzz3nEFmCZ1jtyvKQkZNQ@0MOxEQoMLAUqei79VhFKTW3gO8AiMD0BYcqFVsOQSAomNvSdmzwznIyezt919hZa2yqtgThc@@xNWWnc1PuazImOBlIZ0dJdOJDtd5z6i3s9nKS0Ml1Bk1eGDRxS/fe8As)

The function f modifies an array of strings in-place. The area around the array must be padded with spaces (a bit constrained). Even though this doesn't exactly meet the requirements most solutions are using, it does conform to the rules if we say that we represent a newline with two spaces (and take array of strings ending in newlines).

#### Ungolfed

```c
f(char**x){
    char **y;
    for (y = x; *y; ++y) {
        char *z;
        for (z = *y; *z; ++z) {
            if (*z != ' ') {
                if (z[1] != ' ' || z[-1] != ' ') {
                    // Horizontal exists
                    if (y[1][z-*y] != ' ' || y[-1][z-*y] != ' ')
                        // Vertical exists
                        *z = '+';
                    else
                        *z = '-';
                } else {
                    // Horizontal doesn't exist
                    if (y[1][z-*y] != ' ' || y[-1][z-*y] != ' ')
                        // Vertical exists
                        *z = '|';
                    else
                        *z = '+';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This was a fun challenge of pointer arithmetic. Using C-style pointer iteration it is easy to get the horizontal neighbors, but the vertical ones were tougher. Luckily the y pointer is still around (which points to the initial value of z) so I can deduce my index from it and use that to access the same element on a different row. It felt very wrong writing `y[-1][z-*y]` as it flies in the face of any reasonable style!

Comment: [120 bytes](https://tio.run/##jVFRboMwDP3nFFbR1DgUja3dDxHqCTgB46NCpYtUaEUrxNJyduaQsKadJtVIxH5@z3biItwVxTCUrPjaNJx3eCkPjQnUohUq4Z0Igg41KrgiXyFX4fJ93Sasy97yTIW8y69dFk4@UnbBVcIUpa9KJ3AUrFfLePURt@v5dR6TH4l@kPUZqo2sGV48INOxFKOrhwBeZTkkOrx4M/hrswXB/qMZeDL/9zRsw3dOC2uGb9kObL9Jc8@GB/at7j9s/7625Zsf3NgwIeA/eUv3TSDqhec8Ik/pDavNfn8o2Emq7aEEZjIIHCzEKny1Hq8Q0WyBFg9MkjwSUGUyFxAEEsFsS9uxoZ2VbPZy@qyps@ZYqbaUwsfeY2vkp3Oz39ZsFDgKgovjN9PCu2q959SL7PVKluLkOoOmTwyauqV7b/gB "C (gcc) – Try It Online")